# How do I call a method in an object without passing a variable that should already be in the object?

Tags: java, object, random, methods, constructor

I am trying to create a dice rolling program to practice writing a program. I am creating a Dice object. I want to be able to create a die and state the number of sides when I create it. Example Dice d6 = new Dice(6). After that I want to be able to just print out the roll result without needing to specify the number of sides. in the call. Right now I have this... System.out.println(d6.rollDie(6));. I would like to be able to just do System.out.println(d6.rollDie); or System.out.println(d6.rollDie()); Having to specify the number of sides each time I call negates the point of having a sides variable in the object.

This is my current Java code.

```
//Main.java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Dice d6 = new Dice(6);
        System.out.println(d6.sides);
        System.out.println(d6.rollDie(6));
    }

}


//Dice.java
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {
    int sides;
    int roll;

    Dice(int sides) {
        this.sides = sides;
    }


    public int rollDie(int sides) {
        this.sides = sides;
        Random random = new Random();
        int result = random.nextInt(sides + 1) + 1;
    
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you pass `sides` to the constructor, what's the point of `public int rollDie(int sides) {`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the sides already configured in the constructor. Just add a method that calls the original rollDie() with that as parameter:

```java
public int rollDie() {
        return rollDie(sides);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear `rollDie` should not take an argument. At least not for the instance method. Also, I recommend [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html). And I'm pretty sure your current implementation has an off-by-one problem (you have a seven sided die, not a six sided one). Putting that all together, might look something like

```
public class Dice {
    private int sides;

    public Dice(int sides) {
        this.sides = sides;
    }

    public static int rollDie(int sides) {
        return 1 + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(sides);
    }

    public int rollDie() {
        return 1 + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(this.sides);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can reduce the `1 +` by using the inherited _[nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#nextInt(int,int))_.

Comment: @Reilas Upper bound exclusive. So that just moves the second `1 +`.

Comment: I didn't mean in terms of steps.  I just meant there is a method to handle lower and upper bounds.  As a note, to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

A method doesn't require parameters.
*[Defining Methods (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)*.

You can access your class [field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html), *sides*, from within the class method, *rollDie*.

```java
public int rollDie()
```

Additionally, you can use the alternate *[Random#nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#nextInt(int,int))* method, which has parameters for a lower and upper bound.

```java
int result = random.nextInt(1, sides + 1);
```

Furthermore, if you will be invoking this method more than once per instance, you can increase the scope of the local *Random* declaration, and place it as a field.

Altogether, your class would be as follows.

```java
public class Dice {
    int sides;
    int roll;
    Random random = new Random();
    
    Dice(int sides) {
        this.sides = sides;
    }

    public int rollDie() {
        return random.nextInt(1, sides + 1);
    }
}
```